# WearableListenerService only starting after application is installed - then never again

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm developing an Android applciation with Android Wear support.

The main application sends data to Android wear apps WearableListenerService, that then makes a notification and displays it.

My problem is that if I restart the Watch, the Android Wear app can never be started again - since the listener service on the wear device doesnt start with the mobile app!

I have tried force closing the app and start it again, reboot the phone - no matter what I do the listenerservice can never be started again.

It works perfectly when I install the app from Android Studio, and it will work until the watch is restarted. (I can reboot the phone and close the app)

Have anyone had a similar problem or know a solution to this?

So I'm providing some more info:

When the watch boots up, I captured this message in the logs (which is apparently the root of the problem):

```
11-27 17:22:08.974      803-830/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller I/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Sent delete request for com.example.distributedmediaplayer
11-27 17:22:09.074      473-509/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.example.distributedmediaplayer appid=10032 user=-1: uninstall pkg
11-27 17:22:09.084      473-517/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Couldn't delete native library directory /data/app-lib/com.example.distributedmediaplayer
11-27 17:22:09.274      473-517/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.example.distributedmediaplayer appid=10032 user=0: pkg removed
11-27 17:22:09.574      803-814/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller I/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Package com.example.distributedmediaplayer was uninstalled.
11-27 17:22:44.721    1166-1182/android.process.acore D/VoicemailCleanupService﹕ Cleaning up data for package: com.example.distributedmediaplayer
11-27 17:22:44.891      637-637/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ PackageReceiver: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.distributedmediaplayer flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService$PackageReceiver (has extras) }
11-27 17:22:44.901      637-637/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.distributedmediaplayer cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
```

So the question becomes, what makes my application uninstall when the device starts?

Comment: did u find solution ?

Answer (score 2):

This `Service` is not running all the time - in fact, it's running only during messages processing. Google Play Services Wear API is responsible for starting your `WearableListenerService`, so as long as it contains correct `IntentFilter` set up in `AndroidManifest` you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: Just to add to what Dmitry said. The RAM memory on watch is limited ~512MB. So Wear OS is aggressive in shutting off services if they are not used. Of course, if the callbacks need to be executed, the OS restarts your service automatically. You do not have to do a thing.

Comment: Ok. Then I have some other problem. Do you know what could hinder my service from starting?

Comment: Also, could it have anyting to do with app versioning? Since it works when it's installed from Android Studio... Or simply that the app is removed from the watch when it's restarted?

Comment: @Joakim.Ahle please, explain your workflow in more details. How you're trying to start the service?

Comment: When I want to make a new notificaction on the Android Wear, I do the following (on the host device):
 * Make sure that the GoogleApiClient is connected
 * Put the relevant data in a putDataMapRequest (And a timestamp to make sure it's never the same)
 * Use the DataApi to send the data.

On the wear device, I have a WearableListenerService. It's declared in the manifest as a intent-filter in a service: 
<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />

I can see the other services on the watch being started after reboot but not this.

Comment: @Joakim.Ahle how do you tracking that the service is not started?

Comment: My debug messages are not shown in logcat and no notifications are shown on the watch.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem recently. Works fine when loaded directly to watch. But when the app packaged with wearable apk is installed on host device the doesn't get installed on watch. In fact I get similar logs. And from that I guess the app is removed from the watch instantly after installing for unknown reasons.

Comment: @AlexanderK https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html#Listen

Comment: this is really big problem that i have encountered. i couldnt find the solution. it works inconcistently.